# Laravel attach on associative key

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent, relationship

I have a **ManyToMany** relationship setup but need to specify a value for the key in my array to attach.

```
$data = request()->validate([
           'homework_title' => '', // string
           'homework_description' => '', // string
            'group_id' => '', // array
        ]); 

$homework = request()->user()->homeworks()->create([
            'homework_title' => $data['homework_title'],
            'homework_description' => $data['homework_description'],
        ]);

$homework->groups()->attach($data['group_id'][key]);
```

group_id is an array and looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "group_id": 1,
    "group_name": "8x/En2"
  },
  {
    "group_id": 2,
    "group_name": "9x/En3"
  }
]
```

How do I specify to attach only the group_id in array?

Comment: Something like `array_pluck($data, 'group_id')` ?

Comment: You can use `array_column($data['group_id'], 'group_id')`.

Comment: tried: `dd(array_column($data['group_id'], 'group_id'));` I still get all the data: `"group_id":[{"group_id":1,"group_name":"8x/En2"}]}"` @TheAlpha

Comment: @Ersoy just tried but still getting all the data like the following: `"group_id":[{"group_id":1,"group_name":"8x/En2"}]}"`

Comment: @sam67 i am not sure about the it but; here is the case https://prnt.sc/srruzq

Comment: @Ersoy this is my log error: `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\array_pluck()`

Comment: @Ersoy I forgot to import the class (stupid me)! also for laravel 7 I used `Arr::pluck()`. thanks for all the help, could not of done this without you!

Comment: @sam67 you are welcome - glad it is solved. Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, with:

> Arr::pluck()

First time round I forgot to **import the class** (stupid me)!

> use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

finally looking like the following:

```
$homework->groups()->attach(Arr::pluck($data['group_id'], 'group_id'));
```